# Can I say Ram has been in Delhi for three years

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Suppose I just want to say that Ram has a three years experience of working in our company. Can I say :

**Ram has worked in our company for three years**?

Similarly, if Ram has a three years experience of being in Delhi then can I say:

**Ram has been in Delhi for three years**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is correct to use "for (time period)" with the present perfect to indicate a state that continues until the present.

However, if Ram doesn't live in Dehli anymore, you would use the past tense "Ram lived in Dehli for three years".

Comment: What about the sentence "Ram has been in Delhi for three years"?

Comment: It is correct to use "for (time period)" with the present perfect to indicate a state that continues until the present.

Comment: Present perfect means we are not sure if still he is in Delhi or not but we just know he has a three years experience of being in Delhi. Right?

Comment: No, the present perfect implies that he is still there (as you have been told in answer to your earlier questions).

Comment: Without adding the duration "for three years" you can express experience.  "He has been in Delhi" or "he has worked in Delhi" means he has the experience of being or working in Delhi. As soon as you add "for three years" the meaning changes.